# Почему не подключается манифест PWA?

Tags: pwa, manifest

Написал валидный (вроде) манифест для PWA. Сделал иконки. Подключил файл манифеста к главной странице сайта. Проверяю через режим разработчика - а там такое:

[image: Dev mode]

Я думаю, что проблема в том, что я неправильно указываю пути к файлам...

Файловая структура:

[image: File structure]

Собственно, как я подключаю файл манифеста на главной странице (/main/index.html), в теге `<head>`:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "theme_color": "#ededed",
    "background_color": "#ededed",
    "display": "standalone",
    "scope": ".",
    "start_url": "/index.html",
    "name": "My Appple Shop",
    "short_name": "Appple",
    "description": "My first online shop",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/icons/icon-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/icons/icon-256x256.png",
            "sizes": "256x256",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/icons/icon-384x384.png",
            "sizes": "384x384",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/icons/icon-512x512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ]
}
```

Как можно исправить эту проблему, которая заключается в том, что браузер "не видит" моего манифеста для PWA?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link rel="manifest" href="/main/manifest.json">
```

или

```html
<link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json">
```

или

```html
<!-- Тут повнимательней -->
<link rel="manifest" href="C://path/to/project/dir/main/manifest.json">
```

Comment: Попробовал, все равно не видит манифеста(

Comment: @dbUser11 как вы запускаете проект?

Comment: сохраняю файл main/index.html -> открываю его -> захожу в режим разработчика и проверяю PWA

Comment: Использовать '/' в начале пути можно тогда, когда вы пользуетесь веб-сервером, который будет интерпретировать его как корень проекта, если вы запускаете с файловой системы (в строке браузера у вас file://), то вы должны указывать либо глобальный путь (C://path/to/project/dir/main/manifest.json) либо правильный относительный ('manifect.json' или './manifest.json').